# htaccess external and internal redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have files like

```
www.example.com/api/Member/view.php
www.example.com/api/Other/view.php
```

My `.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex view.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Now i call the above api like `www.example.com/api/Member/`
It's working but i need to remove trailing slash how to do this.

I need to call like this `www.example.com/api/Member`

Comment: `but i need to remove trailing slash` - I would strongly recommend not to remove a trailing slash after a real directory path

Comment: @anubhava but why?

Comment: I can also also ask but why do you want to remove it? :) Anyway it is due to security reason. It may expose your directory content. Please read more about it by searching on net

Comment: So best option is change the file structure.

Comment: It is fine already. `www.example.com/api/Member/` is good friendly URL

Comment: I think it's not looks well. Because it's REST API url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225656/discussion-between-sabish-m-and-anubhava).